# Вращение графического примитива

Tags: c++, qt, графика

Здравствуйте! Возникла такая проблема. Надо реализовать вращение такой фигуры
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Набросал по быстрому код, изображение вертится, но первый сектор постепенно увеличивается и покрывает собой весь круг.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

```
    float radius2;
    if (width() > height())
        radius2 = (height() - 100) / 2;
    else
        radius2 = (width() - 100) / 2;
    QPainter painter(this);
    QPointF center = QPointF(width() / 2, height() / 2);
    QRectF rect = QRectF(center.x() - radius2, center.y() - radius2, radius2*2, radius2*2);

    qreal fAngle = (2 * 180 )/8;
    qreal fAngle2 = fAngle;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::green));
            painter.drawPie(rect,fAngle*16*i + (angle/180.)*M_PI,fAngle2*16 + (angle/180.)*M_PI);
        }
    else {
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::blue));
            painter.drawPie(rect,fAngle*16*i + (angle/180.)*M_PI,fAngle2*16+(angle/180.)*M_PI);
        }
    }
```

angle изначально равно 0, увеличивается в этом событии

```
void MainWindow::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event) {
    angle += 20;
    repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй угол в функции drawPie это угол в основании сектора, а не угол "до которого рисовать", как ты, вероятно, предположил. см. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawPie . Соответственно, не нужно его увеличивать со временем.

`painter.drawPie(rect,fAngle*16*i + (angle/180.)*M_PI,fAngle2*16);`